# What is the terminology difference between Hot, Ballistic and Thermal Electrons

Tags: electrons, solid-state-physics, temperature, terminology

In the realm of injection of electrons into a solid what are the difference between hot, ballistic and thermal electrons?

Is the injected electron ballistic electron? Are they mutually exclusive terms? When does a ballistic electron become a hot electron? When is proper to use which terminology?

Comment: As you note, a thermal electron is one in thermal equilibrium in the solid. A hot electron is at a higher energy, and that can come from being injected 'hot', or being excited by, say, photon absorption. A ballistic electron is one that has retained its original energy, has not scattered, over a significant enough distance (usually device geometry defined). Eventually it would scatter and thermalize, but the material has few enough scattering centers that it doesn't happen while transiting.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks. Would be proper if I call the backscattered and secondary electrons (in scanning electron microscopy) as hot electrons while they are in the material?